# FFMPEG and AWS: What's the most efficient way to handle this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I'm new to AWS and I originally built the FFmpeg functions on my Node.JS API. But I realized this is the wrong way to do it in a real-world app, and that you need to use separate Lambda functions in AWS that handle the video editing separately from the main server.

I'm mainly a front-end developer but I'm open to learning new things.

I basically have the following process in my app:

- User uploads video.
- I need to take that video and add a watermark to it.
- I then need a copy of the watermarked video in a smaller resolution.
- I then need a 6 seconds GIF of the smaller resolution video.
- Finally, I need to upload the 3 edited files (2 .mp4's and 1 .gif) to S3, and remove the original, non-watermarked video.

Here are my questions to be clear:

- Should I upload the original file to S3 or to the server? And why?
- Is the process above doable in a single Lambda function? Or do I need more Lambda functions?
- How would you handle this problem, personally?

I originally built it by chaining one function to the next with promises, but AWS seems like a different world of doing things and the way I originally built it would not work.

Thanks a lot.

**Update**
Here are some tests I did with a couple videos:

|  | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 | Test 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original video resolution | 1080p | 1080p | 1080p | 1080p | 480p |
| Original video duration | 23 minutes | 15 minutes | 11 minutes | 3.5 minutes | 5 minutes |
| Step 1 duration (Watermarking original video) | 30 minutes | 18 minutes | 14 minutes | 4 minutes | 2 minutes |
| Step 2 duration (Watermarking lower resolution) | 5 minutes | 3 minutes | 3 minutes | 1 minute | skip (already low res) |
| Step 3 duration (6 seconds GIF creation) | negligible (15 seconds) | negligible (10 seconds) | negligible (7 seconds) | negligible | negligible |
| Total | ~35 minutes | ~21 minutes | ~17 minutes | ~5 minutes | ~2 minutes |

Comment: Is your server an EC2 instance?

Comment: If you're looking to do serverless orchestration between multiple Lambdas, this sounds like the perfect use case for [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I haven't built the AWS server yet, but yes, I was thinking of using an EC2 instance or Elastic Beanstalk (which seems to always use EC2).

Comment: Oh! Okay, it'd be worth removing 'server' here and replacing it with 'API' as it sounds like you have an existing solution. Do all of your processes take less than 15 minutes?

Comment: S3. Lambda vs. EC2 depends on the size / length of the videos, maybe 15 minute of operation is not long enough to accomplish those tasks.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary you're right indeed, it's an API. I would say the actual FFmpeg functions take less than 15 minutes in most cases I've tried (I can also add a file size limit to prevent this). Should I also include the time it takes to upload the original video to S3 or just the editing process?

Comment: @RedVic Can you add time estimates for doing each of the above steps next to the bullet points?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary just added a table with some tests. I hope it's clear enough. Can't really establish an average since the variance would be very big, so I came to the conclusion I should add a maximum time duration on the original video, say of 5-8 minutes. Do you think I should use Lambda on shorter videos and something else for larger ones? I don't know what that something else could be though. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For what it's worth, Lambda is a very expensive way to do this.  Also, you can do steps #1 and #2 simultaneously, which may save you a bit of CPU because you won't be decoding the original multiple times.

Comment: @Brad are you saying I can add the watermark (overlay) plus text and make a copy with a lower resolution in one single step? In regards to Lambda being expensive, what else would you recommend to accomplish this? I'm building an MVP and don't even know how many users will use my platform yet.